# filter renderdatatable shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a datatable on my shiny server that is defined in server.R as follows:

```
output$datamining_table <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(values$datamining_list,selection="single",
                                                       option=list(lengthMenu = list(c(5, 10,20, -1), c('5', '10','20', 'All')),
                                                                   pageLength = 10,scrollX=T),filter = "top",rownames = F))
```

I also have a selectizeInput in my ui.R with a button. When I select a specific value of my selectizeInput and click on the button, I would like the datatable below to be filtered on the values of my selectizeInput.

For example:

DataTable:

- Name1   valueA
- Name2   valueB
- Name1   valueC
- Name3   valueD

If in the selectizeInput I select Name1 and then click on my button, I would like my datatable to look like:

- Name1   valueA
- Name1   valueC

with the filter criteria of the first column set to Name1 so that I can unfilter it.
Would someone have an idea of how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT:
Here is a reproducible code:

```
    library(shiny)
library(DT)
runApp(list(

  ui=
    div(selectizeInput("selectInput","filter",c("a","b","c"),options=list(maxItems=1,create = F,onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
    dataTableOutput("datamining_table")
      ),

  server=function(input, output, session) {
    values <- reactiveValues()
    values$datamining_list <- data.frame(name =c("a","b","c"),
                                         value = c(1,2,3))
    output$datamining_table <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(values$datamining_list,selection="single",
                                                             option=list(lengthMenu = list(c(5, 10,20, -1), c('5', '10','20', 'All')),
                                                                         pageLength = 10,scrollX=T),filter = "top",rownames = F))
  }))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be helpful.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)

    ### User Interface
    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
      mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
    selectizeInput("selectInput",label ="Filter", choices= NULL, selected = NULL)
    ),
    fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("datamining_table")
       )
     )
     )
    )


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){

  myDataFrame <- data.frame(name =c("a","b","c"),
                            value = c(1,2,3))

  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'selectInput', choices = c('a','b','c'), server = TRUE)

  filterData <- reactive({
      myDataFrame[which(myDataFrame$name == input$selectInput),]

  })

  output$datamining_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(filterData(),selection="single",rownames = F)
  })


})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks it is almost perfect. It filters the table correctly, however it is not possible to remove the filter on the specific name (even with filter="top", the precedent values are not there anymore. I will add a button to retrieve the previous values then I think. thanks a lot!

Comment: @StaP: Sorry I was not able to understand your problem. If you want to remove the filter, you can use the back arrow or delete key to remove the filter, if you want multiple options to be selected in the selectizeInput, you can add the parameter "multiple= TRUE" inside selectizeInput("selectInput",....) Hope this is what you were looking for.